# Javascript: Stop Code Execution with Conditional Statement in Nested Functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, if-statement

I want to validate some values with javascript and the though process is like this:

1. I fire an event when user submits form
2. Javascript gets the values and validates them. If they are correct continue with number three, if not, return abortively.
3. Make ajax request

Here is my submit function:

```
submitLoginForm: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // get the values
    var object = this._getFormValues();

    // make ajax request
    this.querySelector('#postLoginForm').body = object;
    this.querySelector('#postLoginForm').generateRequest();
},
```

This is the function that grabs the values

```
_getFormValues: function () {
    var email = this.querySelector('#email').value;
    var password = this.querySelector('#password').value;
    var remember = this.querySelector('#remember').value;

    this._validate(email, password);

    return { 'email': email, 'password': password, 'remember': remember };
}
```

And this is the function that validates the fields or returns

```
_validate: function (email, password) {                
    if (email === '' || password === '') {
        var elements = this.querySelectorAll('.form-group');

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].className += ' has-error';
        };

        this.hasError = true;
        this.errorMessage = 'Email and Password are required fields.'

        return;
    }
},
```

Till now I used early return like this:

```
if ('email' === '') {
    return;
}

makeAjaxRequest();
```

But since I have nested functions, I wonder how to abort the process completely, if the fields don't validate.

Something like an `exit()` function would be nice.

Comment: Have you looked at [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach would be to just decouple some of your nesting. Prefer returning a bool to make control flow like this easy. So, just moving some of your code around, I would do this:

Your submit function:

```
submitLoginForm: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // get the values
  var object = this._getFormValues();

  if(this._validates(object)) {
    // make ajax request
    this.querySelector('#postLoginForm').body = object;
    this.querySelector('#postLoginForm').generateRequest();      
  } else {
    // moved this from validation 
    var elements = this.querySelectorAll('.form-group');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].className += ' has-error';
    };
  }
},
```

get form values

```
_getFormValues: function () {
  var email = this.querySelector('#email').value;
  var password = this.querySelector('#password').value;
  var remember = this.querySelector('#remember').value;

  return { 
      'email': email,
      'password': password, 
      'remember': remember 
  };
}
```

Your validator:

```
_validate: function (values) {                
  var email = values.email
  var passw = values.password

  if (email === '' || password === '') {
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
},
```

I think I got everything - but it's a starting point anyway. Decouple each function from other tasks and it makes everything much easier.

Comment: Would you say that it is a generally good approach to have functions decoupled?

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness - Absolutely, and others should agree too. Each function should _ideally_ do one thing. Things will inevitably get nested, but if everything only does one thing it's much easier to reason about and make changes.

Answer (score 2):

I think an improved design here would be a better approach. Why does your _getFormValues do any validation? If you decouple the two functions your code is both more clear and you can easily "early return". I would
 1. Save what is returned from _getFromValues into a variable 
 2. Query that Object for empty values ('email === '')
3. Then if appropriate fields are filled in validate then do ajax call. If not, notify the user and DO NOT validate or ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at some `Promises` implementations.

jQuery [$.Deferred()](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object or [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) implementations. It also works great if your nested functions must run asynchronously.

```
//quick example
submitLoginForm: function (event) {

    var data = _getFormValues();

    _submit(data).then(
        function () {
            //SUCCESS
            //update UI accordantly
        },
        function (error) {
            //FAIL
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}

_submit: function (data) {
    var $q = new $.Deferred();

    //AT ANY POINT, run $q.resolve() if you've got a success;
    //OTHERWISE, run $q.reject() to trigger a failure.

    if (_validate() == false) {
        $q.reject("validation failed");       
    }

    makeAjax("/api/foo", function () {
        //ajax success
        $q.resolve(jsonFromServer); 
    })

    return deferredObj.promise();
}
```

Your function `_submit()` will return a promise object that will then run a success or fail function depending on if you run a `resolve` or `reject` call. This is great for sync or async with several nested functions.